# Problem with passing list pointer to a function

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

In my program I have a list which is a pointer `list<COffenceUnit*>* m_attack = nullptr;` I initialize this list like that: `m_attack = new list<COffenceUnit*>();` in the constructor. At some point in the code I want to send this list to another constructor as a reference. This is the constructor that receives the list:

```
GameMap::GameMap(const std::list<CDefenceUnit*>* &defenseUnits, const std::list<COffenceUnit*>* &offenseUnits)
{
    mGameMap = new int* [GRID_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; ++i)
        mGameMap[i] = new int[GRID_SIZE];

    updateMap(defenseUnits, offenseUnits);
}
```

However the compiler throws an error that says:

```
Error   C2664   'GameMap::GameMap(const GameMap &)': cannot convert argument 1 from
'std::list<CDefenceUnit *,std::allocator<_Ty>> **' to 'const std::list<CDefenceUnit *,std::allocator<_Ty>> *&'
```

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: You are confusing yourself with all the use of `*` and `&`. You are probably trying to pass it like `&m_attack` to the constructor when you should use `m_attack`. Please post a [mcve]. Also why do you have a pointer to a list as a member, and not simply a list? And why does the list have pointers in it and not objects? Using pointers for everything is very bad style in `c++`. Raw pointer should almost always be avoided.

Comment: `'GameMap::GameMap(const GameMap &)'` is not a part of the code you are showing. Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call the function with a pointer-to-pointer-to-list (`std::list<...>**`), but the function expects a pointer-to-list (`std::list<...>*`), so the conversion fails.

Dereference the argument to remove one level of pointer. For example if you had `GameMap(defenseUnits)`, then change that to `GameMap(*defenseUnits)`.

---

Also you should almost never `new` std containers, so to initialize your `m_attack`, it's recommended to do it without `new` (i.e. without dynamic allocation), like so:

```
list<COffenceUnit*> m_attack;
```

Then you also don't need to do `m_attack = list<COffenceUnit*>();` later, because the list is already default initialized by the list's constructor.

This also helps you avoid multiple levels of pointers, such as in `std::list<...>**`.

---

Also you probably want `std::vector` instead of `std::list`, the latter is rarely a better choice.